# React-native android issues with Windows 10

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I am running react-native on windows 10 and I'm having a bunch of issues. 
Firstly, at the root directory of the project, when I run

```
react-native run-android
```

I get this error:

> JS server already running. Building and installing the app on the
>   device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug... Could not install
>   the app on the device, read the error above for details. Make sure you
>   have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up
>   your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

And running it with --stacktrace --info did not help. 
I then decided to manually do what the run-android script seems to be trying to achieve by going into the android directory and build my self by running

```
cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug
```

That, produced a bunch of result but still ended in error.

> :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not
>   incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>   C:\Users\jiangyaokai\workspace\maincourse\android\app\src\main\java\com\maincourse\MainApplication.java:30:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               new CodePush(this.getResources().getString(R.strings.reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey),
>   this, BuildConfig.DEBUG),
>                                                           ^   symbol:   variable strings   location: class R
>   C:\Users\jiangyaokai\workspace\maincourse\android\app\src\main\java\com\maincourse\MainApplication.java:30:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               new CodePush(this.getResources().getString(R.strings.reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey),
>   this, BuildConfig.DEBUG),
>                                ^   symbol: method getResources()
>
> 2 errors :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.  Compilation failed; see the
>     compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 8.109 secs

I wonder what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet from your error message:

```
MainApplication.java:30: error: cannot find symbol new CodePush(this.getResources().getString(R.strings.reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey), this, BuildConfig.DEBUG), ^ symbol: method getResources()
```

it looks like it has something to do with **[CodePush](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push)** plugin that you are using.

Could you follow the setup instruction here: https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#android-setup and try again.

Comment: But it seems like it's not just CodePush, R.strings is also having issues, if it was only CodePush then I could have removed that, but it's not. I just wonder how can R.strings not be recognized.

Comment: @user1380898 try `gradlew clean` inside `android/`.

Comment: @Baja Can't thank you enough for this `gradlew clean`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

symbol: variable strings location: class R

this is caused by the fact that R only has string but not strings, not sure why the code (auto generated) refers to strings.

symbol: method getResources()

This is missing because "this" refers to the inner class, wheres getResources() is only found in the outer class.

Overall, basically the code was wrong and correctly could not be compiled.

Thanks to all.